# Is anyone familiar with the term "magladize?" (sp?)

Tags: composition, octave

One of my former music professors used the term "magladize" (sp?) when referring to music composed in octaves but I can't find any references to it. Can anyone verify what I'm talking about including providing the proper spelling?

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something obvious, this is quite a head-scratcher. Any clues? A sample sentence using the word? Was it used as a verb, an adjective, an adverb? Was the professor foreign? Any music in octaves, or only ancient vocal music?

Comment: I assume it's a verb (like aggrandize, oxidize, bastardize) but I don't recognize the word itself or any musically-relevant 'magla' or 'maglad' root. [apparently 'magla' means *fog* in Croatian and *wander* in Filipino...](https://lingo2word.com/lingodetail.php?WrdID=100836)

Comment: Let's wait for more information, it makes no sense to assume the part of speech when we don't know its correct form yet.

Comment: Is it possible the word was "madrigal-ize"?

Comment: magla diže in Croatian means "the fog rises", according to google translate. I don't really see how that helps, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to venture to guess that your professor was using the term, **Magadis**.

According to [Elson's Music Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/cu31924021631340/page/n133):

Magadis (Gr.) (mâ-*gä*-dîs) The name of an ancient Greek treble instrument, furnished with double strings tuned in octaves, like those of a three-stop harpsichord.

Pictured here:

[image]

This seems to fit considering the similar spelling and nature of the tuning in octaves... and, the fact that it sounds like (given the little info provided) your professor was using the term more like an adjective than as a verb; describing music composed in octaves instead of describing a method of composing in octaves...